# Merge values from multiple rows and delete. Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, upsert

I have a table of user availabilities. Each row has a `start time` and `end time` as time stamps.

When I insert a new row, I check whether the row overlaps another availability row for that user, if it does the existing row is updated, if not a new row is added.

The problem is when the new availability overlaps two existing rows.

e.g.

```
'2018-09-01 10:00:00' - '2018-09-01 13:00:00',
'2018-09-01 14:00:00' - '2018-09-01 16:00:00'
```

and the user wants to add:

```
'2018-09-01 11:00:00' - '2018-09-01 17:00:00'.
```

In this case, the first row will be updated but the second row would stay there.

How can I remove/ merge all rows that overlap?

I'm using PostgreSQL

My SQL

```
do $$
      begin

        /* Overlapps availabilty */
        IF EXISTS (
          SELECT *
          FROM availabilities
          WHERE ('${startTime}', '${endTime}') OVERLAPS (availabilities.startTime, availabilities.endTime)
          AND availabilities.therapist = ${therapist}
        ) THEN
          UPDATE availabilities
          SET startTime = LEAST(availabilities.startTime, '${startTime}'::timestamp), endTime = GREATEST(availabilities.endTime, '${endTime}'::timestamp)
          WHERE therapist = ${therapist}
          AND ('${startTime}', '${endTime}') OVERLAPS (availabilities.startTime, availabilities.endTime);

        /* New availabilty */
        ELSE
          INSERT INTO availabilities
            (therapist, startTime, endTime)
          VALUES (${therapist}, '${startTime}', '${endTime}');
        END IF;

      end
      $$
```

UPDATE

I got this working with Michel Milezzi but also added an INSERT before.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Based on the two sample rows and the to-be-inserted row, what exactly is the outcome you are looking for? One row covering 10:00 to 17:00? Two rows? Why would the second row "stay" that would create another conflict with the newly insert (or updated) row?

Comment: I want the second row to be removed and the first row to go from 10:00 to 17:00. So there would only be one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

In order to take the minimum start time and the maximum end time of any overlapping rows you could mix `DELETE` with `RETURNING` and `INSERT`:

```
WITH overlapping AS (
    DELETE FROM
        availabilities 
    WHERE 
        (starttime, endtime) OVERLAPS ('2018-09-01 11:00:00','2018-09-01 17:00:00') 
        AND therapist = 1
    RETURNING 
        therapist, 
        starttime, 
        endtime    
)
INSERT INTO  
    availabilities (therapist, starttime, endtime) 
SELECT 
    therapist, 
    least(min(starttime), '2018-09-01 11:00:00'), 
    greatest(max(endtime),'2018-09-01 17:00:00') 
FROM
    overlapping
GROUP BY
    therapist;
```

---

**Previous answer:**

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but it seems that you were pretty close to the answer:

```
--sample
CREATE TABLE availabilities (therapist, starttime, endtime) AS 
    VALUES 
        (1, '2018-09-01 10:00:00'::TIMESTAMP, '2018-09-01 13:00:00'::TIMESTAMP),
        (1, '2018-09-01 14:00:00', '2018-09-01 16:00:00'),
        (1, '2018-10-01 14:00:00', '2018-10-01 16:00:00'),
        (2, '2018-09-01 14:00:00', '2018-09-01 16:00:00');

--remove overlapping availabilities    
DELETE FROM 
    availabilities 
WHERE 
    (starttime, endtime) OVERLAPS ('2018-09-01 11:00:00','2018-09-01 17:00:00') 
    AND therapist = 1;

--insert new availability
INSERT INTO 
    availabilities (therapist, starttime, endtime) 
VALUES 
    (1, '2018-09-01 11:00:00','2018-09-01 17:00:00');
```

You also could add an exclusion constraint to validate it before insert operation:

```
--In order to use scalar values (e.g.: therapist) on gist indexes we need this extension
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
--Now we can add our new constraint
--Be careful with timezone issues, tsrange will discard timezone data
ALTER TABLE availabilities 
    ADD EXCLUDE USING gist(therapist WITH =, tsrange(starttime, endtime) WITH &&);
```

More info about range operators [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE).

Comment: That's cool but what if the new row overlaps a row that started before it? The existing row would be deleted. I wanted the new row to take the minimum start time and the maximum and time of any overlapping rows

Comment: @JamesJohnson I think I understand now. I edited my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: woo, that works, thanks a lot! I had to update the code though, I added an insert before, otherwise 'overlapping' would be empty. Is that the best way or would there be a better way? Thanks

Comment: You're absolutely right. I think that's a good way, just be careful with concurrency issues. Regards